# SVG image hover animation not shown in css background

Tags: css, svg

I'm having trouble displaying an animated SVG file correctly when used in a CSS background

## My Setup

### SVG file

The SVG file I use is basically a semi-transparent circle that gets fully opaque when hovered. It works as I expect it to work.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="svg2">
      <circle
         cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill="#61737b" id="circle4" style="fill-opacity:0.5">
         <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="fill-opacity" 
               from="0.5" to="1" dur="0.2s" begin="mouseover" fill="freeze" />
         <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="fill-opacity" 
               from="1" to="0.5" dur="0.2s" begin="mouseout" fill="freeze" /></circle>
    </svg>
```

### HTML/CSS code

The background property of `toolbarbutton` from the code below contains the same SVG, encoded as base64. This should have the same behavior as an external file like in my real world case.

```css
toolbarbutton {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<toolbarbutton></toolbarbutton>
```

## The Problem

The initial state of the SVG background is exactly the same as in the pure SVG case.
However as you hover the `toolbarbutton` nothing happens. I would expect it to do the same as in the pure SVG example.

Did I make a mistake or is this not supported? And if so how do I work around this? Note that in my real world case I'd like to have a hover animation for `toolbarbutton` that is not possible with CSS but with SVG. And I can't change anything in the HTML code.

Comment: images are not interactive so if they contain SMIL or CSS animations it can't be triggered by things such as hovering. Any animation must be time based only. You'd need to display your SVG via an iframe or object tag or have it inline in the HTML page itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<svg> <animate>` markup won't work when using an svg as a background image. In the example you gave, you can use a light circle and a dark circle along with `:hover` and `transition`, like so (note that I'm using straight svg in the `url()` - that works generally speaking, though the way I wrote it probably won't work on IE 10/11 or Edge. I'm leaving it as is so you can see what I've done. See https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/ for more on this side issue)

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* changed this */
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill="#b0b9bd"></circle></svg>');
  /* added this */
  transition: 0.2s;
}
/* added this */

div:hover {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill="#61737b"></circle></svg>');
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

But of course that will limit you to effects available in CSS. If you have to use SVG, you might be able to have an absolutely-positioned SVG under (lower `z-index`) some other div - but if you can't change the markup at all, that's not a solution.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately that doesn't solve my real problem. The example with the circle was a simplified one of course.
But now I at least know that what I tried to achieve is not possible.
Your answer might still be useful for others though.

Comment: Was afraid of that, hopefully it gets you headed in a useful direction

Comment: animate does work in SVG when used as a background, it's the triggering of the animate interactively (mouseover, mouseout) that doesn't work. If you just had an animate that ran all the time that would be fine.

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil that won't work in IE or Edge, Edge hasn't publicized any plans to support it in the future, and Chrome and Opera are talking about dropping it. (Once again, props to FF @RobertLongson!) Scindix, depending on exactly what your real goal is, this [SMIL is dead! Long live SMIL! A Guide to Alternatives to SMIL Features](https://css-tricks.com/smil-is-dead-long-live-smil-a-guide-to-alternatives-to-smil-features/) might be useful